# Gradle dependencies not available in custom test folder

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have created a custom test folder and added in the test source sets as follow :

```
   sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs += "src/customTest/java"
    }
    test {
        java.srcDirs += "src/customTest/java"
    }
}
```

Everything is Ok excepted that the dependencies configured for test(Implementation) nor androidTest(Implementation) are available in the class inside src/customTest/java,
i have tried to refresh the dependencies clear the cache but nothing change,

There is only junit dependencie available, all others are not found(configured the same way with testImplementation)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the directory, instead of adding another one with `+=`

```
java.srcDir = ["src/customTest/java"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my goal was to add this folder to the existing source sets, not to replace it, this folder for example could contains utils available for both instrumented and unit test

Comment: The most easy would be to nest whatever directory into the existing directory structure... eg. so that you could have one directory for whatever `TestSuite` you have in there (the test framework behaves rather rigid and working against it is hopeless).

Comment: I have noticed also that Android Studio consider it as androidTest, when i remove the androidTest sourceSets pointing to the folder, then it is considered as unit test and i have my dependencies

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be to declare the commons dependencies(used in the shared test folder) as debug, eg. : `debugImplementation`.. instead of `test/androidTest`